# How do dependencies work with pyinstaller?

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I'm pretty beginner in python, for my classes final project I thought it would be cool to make my program an executable. I found pyinstaller and I figured everything out and I have the .exe, except it can't find this text file I made. I store all the data in a text file, how do I let my program find it?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

For files that aren't scripts (images, text files etc.), you have to have the .exe file and these non-script files in the same directory.

For example:

```
program\
    main.exe
    info.txt
```

If your .exe file is outside this directory, it can't find your text file. I'm assuming you are using the `open()` function to access your text file and this would mean that that function is looking in the directory that your executable is in for the text file.

Example:

```
program\
    info.txt

desktop\
    main.exe
```

In this case, your program is looking for info.txt in the desktop directory.

You could get around this by hosting the text file online somewhere.

Hope this helps!